# What would you say "Orbanization " refers to?

Tags: meaning

In this article, [The Attack on Big Mouse Is Also an Assault on Democracy](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/25/opinion/republicans-florida-disney-conspiracy-theories.html), there is this excerpt:

> So the fight over Disney is actually a symptom of a much broader and more troubling development: the QAnonization and Orbanization of one of America’s major political parties, which is putting our democracy at risk.

What is "Orbanization" refering to?

Comment: "Orbanization" is apparently a neologism derived from Viktor Orbán, a ruler considered autocratic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Orb%C3%A1n . Perhaps a more extreme example might be Idi Amin, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idi_Amin , but one couldn't use "Aminization" without confusion with decomposition of proteins.

Comment: It means moving the country to the right and having people follow you. Like Orban in Hungary.

Comment: @Lambie That seems to me to be an answer!